# How can i retrieve data from such database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to retrieve the value and the time, but I can't get there, it keeps giving me the value as null in the logs. I was wondering if it's necessary to get the unique_id, if yes how can I do it.

[image: Screenshot of Realtime Database]

```
valueRef = myRef.child("user_id").child("ASSETS").child("cash at bank");

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        valueRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Long value = ds.child("values").getValue(Long.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is" + value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i did but still it gives the value is null

Comment: Pretty vague question but your child node is incorrect. It should be Cash at bank, not cash at bank (the actual node name is with an uppercase 'C')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be the correct way to solve your problem:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Long value = ds.child("values").getValue(Long.class);
}
```

In your reference you are already looking into the new child with the unique id and getting its `DataSnapshot`. All you have to do is reference the child of it, which is `values`, and get its value.